# android: special screen resolutions (Slider, 720p...)

Tags: android

I've created different directories for my android layouts as follows :

- 1) res/layout
- 2) res/layout-small
- 3) res/layout-large
- 4) res/layout-xlarge

Most of the screen resolutions out there i've reached with this, but i've problems getting it all.

e.g. All screen resolutions with (Slider) and the 720p Galaxy Nexus doesnt work! Also some FWQVGA or XGA resolutions.

Can anybody tell me WHICH DIRECTORIES i also need to get all screens correctly?

THX 4 help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing "layout-normal", but the small, normal, large, xlarge qualifiers are for physical screen size (the diagonal). It's better practice to use the dpi qualifiers layout-ldpi, layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi. See [the guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more details.

Comment: thx, i ll check this. btw : layout-normal is not necessary, cause its the default layout. i've read this in the screen guideline.